# get element where the innerhtml text matches a value - Hopscotch and javascript

Tags: javascript

Im using hopscotch to create a tour. Im writing the tour without access to the actual html so i cant change it to have unique ids. Because of this i need to access the element based on the innerhtml of the element because there is lots of divs with this same name. Heres the link to hopscotch

http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/

And here is an example of the code:

```
 <div class="myContent">
     <div class="myTitle">
         Section 1
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="myContent">
     <div class="myTitle">
         Section 1
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="myContent">
     <div class="myTitle">
         Section 2
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="myContent">
     <div class="myTitle">
         Section 3
     </div>
 </div>
```

So i have a tour that looks like this:

```
  var tour = {
  id: "welcome_to_my_tour",
  steps: [
    {
      title: "First Tour",
      content: "The following short tour will guide you through everything you need to know",
      target: "header",
      placement: "bottom",
      xOffset: "center"
    }
```

For target you usually just put the id of the element but of course that wont work because there is lots of elements with the same id. I see from the documentation you can also use:

```
target: document.querySelector("#content p")
```

so i was thinking it might be possible to access it with something like this:

```
target: document.querySelector(".myTitle").innerHTML("section 3")
```

Of course that is not real code but you can see where im going, i tried googling around and just keep coming up with how to read the value with innerHTML but i cannot figure how to access an element based on the innerHTML value or if its even possible, if not is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Tried http://api.jquery.com/contents/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector comes in handy here. You could do this:

`target: $(".myContent :contains('Section 3')")[0]`

document.querySelector does not support `:contains`, but you could use it inside [IIFE (immediately-invoked function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). It is way more verbose than jQuery though:

```
target: (function(){
  var titles = document.querySelectorAll(".myTitle");
  for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    if(titles[i].innerHTML.indexOf('Section 3') >= 0) {
      return titles[i];
    }
  }
}())
```